# Wcf service server - authentication with usernametoken

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-security

we are trying to create server from given demo wsdl. Wsdl does not contains security but we need implement usernametoken where request header looks like this:

```
<soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" env:mustUnderstand="true">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7dd435a5-b8bb-4388-bba3-f77512a14351">
                <wsse:Username>CES</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">e8I23Z92JGgSREAb=</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">v21JzUcrKZiZ7MC==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2017-10-13T13:00:02.221Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                <wsse:Embedded wsse:ValueType="http://www.asktirweb.org/security/authentication/username" wsu:Id="alex"/>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </wsse:Security>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.asktirweb.org/services/TIRAccountingService-1/sendInvoice</Action>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:321a0dff-61a8-4eae-8934-7f06e8d87648</MessageID>
        <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://wiesbaden:8040/askdemo/hs/AskTirWebDemo/WsSecurityRequests</To>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
    </soap:Header>
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below custom binding, it might be useful to you.

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="mybinding">
     <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10">
     </textMessageEncoding>
     <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" >
     </security>
     <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
   </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

And the request body captured by Fiddle.
[image]
Besides, can we use the WSDL file to generate the client configuration, which has contained the essential binding type and security authentication mode? Like the below Tools.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe
By default, it is a built-in tool in VS Developer Command Prompts.

> svcutil https://vabqia969vm:21011

It will generate the output.config in the current directory, it contains the binding configuration to be used in WCF.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.